# Kafka connect API client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Trying to write data from kafka to hdfs. It is not documented anywhere how to use Confluent's kafka-connect-hdfs Java API.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use the Java API for. KafkaConnect can be used from the command line or REST API... even if you are triggering connectors from Java, [the REST API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest) will still work.

Some documentation to get you started:

First, the KafkaConnect quickstart, just to make sure your system is in good shape before trying to do something advanced:
http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/intro.html#quickstart

If you are new to Kafka, maybe even start earlier with the Kafka quickstart:
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Once stand-alone more works, try switching to distributed mode and check out [the REST API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest)

Then try the HDFS connector. Either start with the quick-start:
http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart

Or the blog tutorial:
http://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-build-a-scalable-etl-pipeline-with-kafka-connect

Hope this helps on your way.

Comment: We have to consume data from kafka stream and dump into HDFS. Small code snippet will help. I am keen to use only Java API

Comment: You can just use a connector for that: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka's Producer Java API to write to Kafka topics.

kafka-connect-hdfs will take messages from topics and put them in HDFS. This does not require Java code.

You run it has shown in the kafka-connect-hdfs quickstart:

```
$ ./bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties \
etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties
```

As of the moment, kafka-connect-hdfs only supports topics with Avro data formats registered with the Kafka Schema Registry.